US rules regarding traveling with cash
When traveling domestic in the US (flying / trains), what rules must one observe / be cognizant of when carrying cash for travel?
Responses to commentary
For this question assume $8000.   I believe JonCuster's comment refer's to civil forfeiture: the money is guilty of a crime (if that is somehow possible).
" A 2020 study found that the median cash forfeiture in 21 states which track such data was $1,300" Reference

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is simply "none".  Do you have some specific reason to believe that restrictions exist?

@NateEldredge - one can find multiple stories of state/local police seizing "large" quantities of cash discovered in, e.g., a traffic stop. Getting it back can become a long ordeal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States

@JonCuster this has nothing to do with any specific laws or rules, it's just a kind of legalized robbery

And in particular, there's nothing about it that's specific to travel.

@NateEldredge Civil forfeiture very commonly occurs to travelers, especially those driving.

To the best of my knowledge know there are no laws that restrict the amount of cash you can carry around domestically.
That doesn't mean, it's a good idea. Cash is inherently unsafe and can easily be lost and stolen. Large amounts of cash can also trigger interest by the authorities as it could be related to a criminal activities. This may result in the cash being seized using "civil forfeiture" even if there is no criminal activity at all.
Unfortunately, there is no real protection against abusive civil forfeiture so this comes down to a risk assessment.

what actions can one take to "shield" them money from civil forfeiture?

When driving: you can and should exercise your 4th and 5th amendment rights. When you get pulled over, you do NOT need to consent to have your car searched and you do NOT need to answer any questions like "do you have any cash or valuables". Unless the cops have probable cause (varies a bit by state) there isn't a whole lot they can do to determine whether you have cash or not and they can't get their hands on it.
When flying: As long as no one knows you are carrying cash they can't seize it. There are anecdotal reports that the TSA informing law enforcement when they see a large wad of cash (potentially for a cut of the take) but that seems to be concentrated at specific airports. People carry all sorts of cash through security all the time so I'm guessing that would only trigger if it looks really unusual.

Regarding driving if you are pulled over.  Anything visible through the car's windows is not protected by the 4th amendment.  However, as seen on innumerable  YT videos, LEO can and will bully people into giving up their rights, and have been known to lie in order to get what they want (The classic "I smell marijuana", which leads to calling for a drug sniffing dog, which falsely alerts, which gives probable cause for a search.)
